# convert python list of bytes to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to convert a list of bytes to list of dictionary

```
mylist = [b'Ruby,events_spec.rb,188,5,613\n',
b'HTML,index.html,14,0,592\n']
```

to something like

```
[{'Filename':"events_spec.rb","Language":Ruby","Blank Lines":"188","Comment Lines":"5","Code Lines":613},{'Filename':"index.html","Language":HTML","Blank Lines":"14","Comment Lines":"0","Code Lines":592}]
```

> Even though 'Filename' is second element in the list , I want
>   'Filename' to be first element of dictionary

Tried something but didn't get desired output

```
mylist = [b'Ruby,events_spec.rb,188,5,613\n',
b'HTML,index.html,14,0,592\n']

list1 = ["Filename","Language","Blank Lines","Comment Lines","Code Lines"]

final_list = []

n_dict = {}
for i in mylist:
    final_list.append(dict(zip(list1,i.decode("ascii").split(","))))

print(final_list)
```

Not Desired Output

```
[{'Filename': 'Ruby', 'Language': '/Users/hariomsingh/Desktop/ignit/Repo/ignite-chute-analytics-backend/spec/requests/events_spec.rb', 'Blank Lines': '188', 'Comment Lines': '5', 'Code Lines': '613\n'}, {'Filename': 'HTML', 'Language': '/Users/hariomsingh/Desktop/ignit/Repo/ignite-chute-analytics-backend/docs/index.html', 'Blank Lines': '14', 'Comment Lines': '0', 'Code Lines': '592\n'}
```

Tried using OrderedDict

```
from collections import OrderedDict
mylist = [b'Ruby,/Users/hariomsingh/Desktop/ignit/Repo/ignite-chute-analytics-backend/spec/requests/events_spec.rb,188,5,613\n',
b'HTML,/Users/hariomsingh/Desktop/ignit/Repo/ignite-chute-analytics-backend/docs/index.html,14,0,592\n']


list1 = ["Filename","Language","Blank Lines","Comment Lines","Code Lines"]

final_list = []

n_dict = OrderedDict()
for i in mylist:
        final_list.append(dict(zip(list1,i.decode("ascii").split(","))))

print(final_list)
```

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered. Until python 3.7 that is.

Comment: (This question does not appear to expect [insert] ordered dictionary semantics and it already starts with an [incorrectly ordered] list. The original code appears on a valid track but entirely misses to "split on a comma".. debugging would have been relevant, and should be expected from developers.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you have to reorder your keywords to match the position of the elements in the source data:

```
list1 = ["Language","Filename","Blank Lines","Comment Lines","Code Lines"]
```

then it's as simple as:

```
mydict = { a : b for a,b in zip( list1, mylist[0].strip().split(',')) }
```

which gives us:

```
{'Blank Lines': '188', 'Comment Lines': '5', 'Code Lines': '613', 'Language': 'Ruby', 'Filename': 'events_spec.rb'}
```

and then you just have to iterate over the all elements in `mylist`.

Comment: Might want to mention that dict isn't ordered until python 3.7

Comment: @MadPhysicist i'm a renegade, still using 2.6 =)

Comment: Then you don't get to decide what order your dict keys show up in.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, and I don't care about the order, anarchy rules! =))

Comment: There's gotta be a better verb to describe what it does :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist English is not my native language, I just use what I hear on the streets! =)

Comment: @lenik But Python 2.6 doesn't have dict comprehensions; you get a `SyntaxError` on the `for`. You can just pass the `zip` to `dict`, and it'll work all the way back to 2.2 or so (whenever they made `dict` callable), although then the `b` literals are a `SyntaxError`s…

Comment: Python 0.9 gives me a `syntax error` on double quotes, `undefined name` on `zip` and `dict`, and `type error: attributeless object` trying to call `strip` as a method rather than `string.strip(…)`… but if you fix all of that, it works, so +1. :)

Comment: @abarnert sorry, it's 2.7.6 -- I have picked just the first and the last numbers... my mind playing tricks on me =)

Comment: Oh, it's cool if you like Python 2.7, after it went all mainstream and sellout, not everyone can enjoy the purity of programming in Python 1.1 while riding a fixie bike and drinking this beer that tastes like PBR but flat and ironically pretending to hate hipsters… or is that pretending not to hate them? I can't remember. :)

Comment: @abarnert don't worry, I have 2.2.3 from 2005 on another box and use it occasionally =)

Answer (score 1):

i write some code for you, you can try this

```
mylist = [b'Ruby,events_spec.rb,188,5,613\n', b'HTML,index.html,14,0,592\n']

new_mylist = []
for mylist_ in mylist:
    mylist_ = mylist_.decode('utf-8')
    mylist_ = mylist_.replace('\n', '')
    values = [i for i in mylist_.split(',')]
    new_mylist.append(values)

new_mylist_tmp = new_mylist
new_mylist = []
my_dict = {}

for i in new_mylist_tmp:
    my_dict = {'Filename':i[1],"Language":i[0],"Blank Lines":int(i[2]),"Comment Lines":int(i[3]),"Code Lines":int(i[4])}
    new_mylist.append(my_dict)

print(new_mylist)
```

Comment: {'Filename':i[1],"Language":i[0],"Blank Lines":int(i[2]),"Comment Lines":int(i[3]),"Code Lines":int(i[4])} This is something I will use when I don't have any solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use **re** module for better output as it will take care of spaces before and after `,` delimiter which the simple `split()` can't.

```
import re 

mylist = [b'Ruby,events_spec.rb,188,5,613\n',b'HTML,index.html,14,0,592\n']

list1 = ["Language", "Filename", "Blank Lines","Comment Lines","Code Lines"]

final_list = []

for i in mylist:        
    final_list.append(dict(zip(list1,re.split("\s*,\s*", i.decode("ascii").strip()))))

print(final_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'Blank Lines': '188', 'Code Lines': '613', 'Filename': 'events_spec.rb', 'Language': 'Ruby', 'Comment Lines': '5'}, {'Blank Lines': '14', 'Code Lines': '592', 'Filename': 'index.html', 'Language': 'HTML', 'Comment Lines': '0'}]
```

Comment: This solves a problem the OP doesn't actually have, while not solving the problem he's asking about.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. I changed the order of items in list. Dictionary is unordered, so it is ok.